# Should input fields be used as ready only information?

Tags: design-patterns, input-fields

I have a license that will be transferred from user "James" to someone in my database (this is enterprise application):

[image]

When I click on the name (it means assigned to) it opens a popup so it goes into "edit" mode

[image]

The field "From" is just "view" only, because it is pulled from the person who owns the license.

When coding in html and using bootstrap, is this using input field correct?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. please style again. in bootstrap doc `readonly` and `disabled` mode looks like same.

Since both ReadOnly and Disabled attributes give the user a way to view the value of the element but don't modify it. While one of them - disabled - provide a visual feedback, the designer needs to choose whether the user can differentiate between a standard element and a non-modified element. 
If you want the user to identify the element is in non-modified mode, use `disabled`.
If you want a non-modified element to appear like the rest of the form elements, use `readonly`.

[image]